# get end of day epoch in shell script bash

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

I want to get end of day epoch in bash.

Eg:

```
date +%s
```

The above command gives current epoch.

I want the end of day epoch of current date.

Comment: Is that the current *local* date, or the current *UTC* date?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply specify that with the `-d` argument.

i.e. `date -d "today 23:59:59" +%s`
where today 23:29:59 is used to get the end of the current day

**Edit** : @[Toby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight) propose the following approach to handle correctly leap seconds `-d 'tomorrow 0 -1second`

If you want the beginning of the day use

```
date -d "today 0" +%s
```

Comment: This assumes GNU `date`, as `-d` is not standard.

Comment: That's not correct on systems that handle leap-seconds properly (where the last minute of the day can have 61 seconds).  You really want `-d 'tomorrow 0 -1second'`.

Answer (score 2):

Using BSD `date`, you can use the `-v`  to adjust the time properly.

```
% date
Tue May 22 09:21:50 EDT 2018
% date  -v 23H -v 59M -v 59S
Tue May 22 23:59:59 EDT 2018
```

Slightly longer, but saving you from having to remember how many hours are in a day, minutes in an hour, etc, by going to midnight tomorrow, then subtracting one second.

```
% date -v +1d -v 0H -v 0M -v -0S -v -1S
          ^      ^     ^      ^     ^
          |      |     |      |     |
          |      +-----+------+     subtract one second
          |            |
          |        reset to midnight
          |
          go to tomorrow
```

(It's a shame `-v` can't take a combination. `date -v+1d0H0MS-1S` would be nice to type. It's not terribly readable or obvious, but easy to parse if you know how `-v` works. Whitespace would make it better: `date -v "+1d 0H 0M 0S -1S"`. #wishfulthinking)

---

A simple but fragile approach is to just round up to the nearest multiple of 86400:

```
$ now=$(date +%s)
$ end_of_day=$(( now - now%86400 + 86399))
```

but this won't take daylight savings into account for the two days where it may be relevant.